# Create a number of variables within a list within loops

Tags: r, list, eval, assign

I'd like to create a number of lists and within each list as I have below:

```
A = list()
B = list()
C = list()
D = list()
A$X = list()
A$Y = list()
A$Z = list()
# ...
D$X = list()
D$Y = list()
D$Z = list()
```

Rather than typing a long list, I have the code below but it doesn't quite work:

```
strVar = LETTERS[1:4]
strGrp = LETTERS[24:26]
for (i in 1:length(strVar)) {
  assign(strVar[i],list())
  for (j in 1:length(strGrp)) {
    # Option 1: Doesn't work and work to make it work along the line
    assign(paste0(strVar[i],'[[\'',strGrp[j],'\']]'),list())
    # Option 2: Does work but want to avoid using eval(parse)
    eval(parse(text=paste0(strVar[i],'$',strGrp[j],'=list()')))       
  }
}
```

Option 1 gives a variable named A[['X']] while option 2 gives variable A which is a list, and within A, there are variables X, Y and Z which is what I want.

What have I done wrong for option 1?  Many thanks.

Comment: can you close the topic if an answer suits you or say why an answer is not satisfying?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel: Thanks!  Sorry, how do I close the topic?

Comment: If the answer suits you, you can check the mark associated to the answer ! This rank the question in the answered category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose a solution with `assign` but this is really bad since **you want function with no side effects** (not modifying the global envrironment in a sneaky way but rather returning a result).

Do not forget `R` paradigm is to pass by value!

Here is a solution with a fair approach approach:

```
library(magrittr)

res = setNames(replicate(3, list()), strGrp) %>% 
    list %>% 
    replicate(4, .) %>% 
    setNames(strVar)

#> res$A
#$X
#list()

#$Y
#list()

#$Z
#list()
```

`l_plyr` can be replaced by `lapply` if you wanna remain base `R`.

For the first approach you want (influence the global environment within a function), you need to mention the `envir` in which you create your variables in `assign`. Here is a way to go:

```
library(plyr)

l_ply(strVar, function(u){
    assign(u, setNames(replicate(3, list()), strGrp), envir=.GlobalEnv)
})

#> A
#$X
#list()

#$Y
#list()

#$Z
#list()
```